# How to trigger building of tests-jar by maven property

Tags: maven, unit-testing, properties

I know how to build the tests-jar by adding the `maven-jar-plugin`. But this requires 14 lines of code at my (module-)POM.

To save lines of code I only want to add a Maven-Propery at my module-POM to work as switch to decide wheter to add the tests-jar or not. And the `maven-jar-plugin` should only be defined at the parent-POM.

So my current solution is:

code at parent-POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>${addTestsJar}</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

code at module-POM:

```
<properties>
    <addTestsJar>test-jar</addTestsJar>
    <!-- 'test-jar' or 'jar' -->
</properties>
```

So now `test-jar` will result in generation of tests-jar and `jar` will not build the tests jar.

Is this a good solution?
Or are there some disadvantages?

PS: To trigger the jests-jar by a profile will not work because activation of profiles is only triggered by System-Properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it, if you use the 'jar' goal I think Maven might run 'jar' twice - once as part of the default build and another time for the execution you added.  You could run with `-X` and check the execution IDs to be sure.

Another way to do this is to use the `skip` parameter of the `test-jar` goal.  By default, this property has the value of the `maven.test.skip` property.  I guess the thinking is to skip the test jar creation if you're skipping test runs?  I see these as two different things; I might want to run the tests without creating the jar.

So with that in mind, I would add this to the parent POM:

```
<properties>
  <skipTestJar>true</skipTestJar>
</properties>

<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>build-test-jar</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-jar</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skipTestJar}</skip>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  <pluginManagement>
</build>
```

And then for any module where I wanted a test jar, I would change the property value:

```
<properties>
  <skipTestJar>false</skipTestJar>
</properties>
```

Alternately, you can set the property on the command line by adding `-DskipTestJar=false`.

Comment: With that code Maven run into `Unrecognised tag: 'skip'` - So this will not work...

Comment: Oops, had skip parameter in wrong place; I fixed it.  See if it works now.

Comment: Yes, thats what I want but with inverted logic.